# What's the frequency of anti lock brakes?

Tags: brakes

After a hard braking incident tonight (almost hit a young cow!) I was explaining to my son (8) about how antilock brakes work and how you can usually feel when they engage as a sort of pulsing through the brake pedal. We were talking about how and why that works but I realized I didn't know really what the frequency of on/off pulse is.

I guess it feels in the 10-20 times per second range but that could be wildly subjective or incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The braking is cycled between 5 to 10 times a second. That is 5Hz to 10Hz.

Some detail can be found here : http://autoditex.com/page/anti-lock-braking-system-abs-9-1.html

Comment: I would agree with you, but it really depends on the manufacturer's solution. GM can have a different pulse width than Chrysler, which can be different from BMW.

Comment: Pulse width - are you talking about the wheel sensor pulses?